# Why Webex accesses my outlook email file?

Tags: windows-11, webex

I just discovered that Webex has access to a random Outlook email file (.ost). Why? Is there a way to limit Webex to only resources it needs to function (ie keyboard, webcam, mic)?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Webex has access to a random Outlook email file. Why?

Webex has integration options with outlook:

> You can connect your Microsoft Outlook account with Webex App to make it easier for you to collaborate with your colleagues. In Outlook, you can check the status of someone in the app, send them a message, or start a call.

Source: [Webex App | Connect your Microsoft Outlook account](https://help.webex.com/en-us/article/yf1gc7/Webex-App-%7C-Connect-your-Microsoft-Outlook-account)

---

#### Is there a way to limit Webex to only resources it needs to function?

You can remove the Webex scheduler add-in:

> If you installed the app yourself and you no longer want to schedule
> meetings using the Webex Scheduler, you can remove the app. If your
> administrator installed the app, contact your administrator to remove
> it.
>
> 1. If you're using Outlook for desktop, select Get Add-ins in the Add-ins group in the Outlook ribbon.
> 2. If you're using Outlook on the web, select More options > Get Add-ins.
> 3. Select My add-ins in the Microsoft 365 Add-ins window.
> 4. Locate the Cisco Webex Scheduler and select More > Remove.

Source: [Schedule and join meetings with Webex Scheduler for Microsoft Outlook](https://help.webex.com/en-us/article/nttajz6/Schedule-and-join-meetings-with-Webex-Scheduler-for-Microsoft-Outlook#id_96829)